# How can I resize an uploaded image based on user input in ASP.NET using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                HttpPostedFile uploadedFile = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);

                using (Bitmap sourceImage = new Bitmap(uploadedFile.InputStream))
                {
                    float ratio = Math.Min((float)192 / sourceImage.Width, (float)192 / sourceImage.Height);
                    int width = (int)(sourceImage.Width * ratio);
                    int height = (int)(sourceImage.Height * ratio);

                    using (Bitmap scaledBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height))
                    {
                        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(scaledBitmap))
                        {
                            graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                            graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

                            graphics.DrawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, width, height);
                        }

                        string scaledImagePath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/scaledImage.png");
                        scaledBitmap.Save(scaledImagePath, ImageFormat.Png);

                        imgPhoto.ImageUrl = "~/Images/scaledImage.png";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code. This uses a fileUpload upload a file. When the Button1 is clicked it shows the uploaded image. Now I have created an input text box which takes a size as input. Now I want to resize the image to the size user provides. Please let me know how can I do it.

Cheers!